# Need to encrypt Custom WordPress Plugins

Tags: wordpress, obfuscation

I have WordPress website. Also I created custom plugins. So what I need is the following:

Is there any way to encrypt my WordPress custom Plugins? because I need to encrypt all our custom plugins and make it downloadable. For example, there is an encryption in WHMCS called ioncube. Likewise is there any encryption method available for custom WordPress plugins.

I have researched about this in Google, but not getting. So can you please help me to find a possible solution for this?

Comment: look at Zend, PHPCodeLock or IonCube

Comment: Hello @amit Can you please explain it briefly, since I am new to this

Comment: This question is far too broad. Briefly though, those three products are _code obfuscators_. They use encryption techniques to make code hard to read, though note that it is reversible. Why not see if there are demo versions you can try? Then, if so, why not try one? They will all come with documentation.

Comment: So you are saying that these three products are good for plugin encryption right?  Also I need to make it as downloadable by entering some activation code  like that. Is it possible?